# Linear regression on original and log-transformed data have different coefficients even after back-transforming, why is that?

Tags: logging, scale, transformation, coefficients, interpretation

I am working with a relatively large dataset (n = 450). Because the distribution of the outcome variable is right-skewed, I tried log-transformed the data to make it more normal, and it worked to normalize the outcome distribution. My outcome variable is continuous. My predictor variable is categorical/binary.

I first ran a simple linear regression (using the lm() function) of the binary predictor variable on the continuous outcome variable, the predictor came out to be marginally statistically significant (p = 0.066), and the slope or b coefficient was 52.83.

I then log-transformed my outcome data using the log() function, and ran a simple linear regression again of the binary predictor variable on the now log-transformed continuous outcome variable. The results came out to be statistically significant (p = 0.02), with a 0.1524 slope or b coefficient. I used the exp() function to back-transform the b coefficient into the original outcome scale, but it came out to be 1.164, which is no where near 52.83, the slope I got using the outcome data in its original scale.

Can someone please help explain why I got such different values for the slope running a simple linear regression on the outcome variable in its original scale and after I log-transformed it?

Can someone provide some guidance on which set of results should I be interpreting? Given that my sample size is larger than 30, can I apply the central limit theorem and just interpret the results from the outcome data in its original scale? Is log-transformation necessary even though my outcome's distribution is right-skewed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The model you are specifying becomes a **level-log** model. The new form of model, given you have one predictor (X) and one dependent variable (y) with intercept (a) is:

```html
<img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\inline&space;y&space;=&space;a&plus;\beta&space;.ln(x)" title="y = a+\beta .ln(x)" />
```

The interpretation of above is: ***If X increases by 1%, we would expect y to increase by (Beta/100) units.***
Mathematically, it is:

```html
<img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\inline&space;\Delta&space;y=%\Delta&space;X.\frac{\beta&space;}{100}" title="\Delta y=%\Delta X.\frac{\beta }{100}" />
```

Given the above formulation, you cannot simply convert your Beta by exponentiating. If you want to predict **y** values you need to multiply the Beta with log-transformed X data.

[Here](http://www.cazaar.com/ta/econ113/interpreting-beta) is informative article with videos for different type of models.